# Mongoid Versioning Scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

Mongoid has built-in versioning when you mix-in the Mongoid::Versioning module.  It works really well for me but I'm inelegantly working with versions on a model.  Let me give you an example.  Assume I'm building a blog app (I'm not).

My model is Post.  Let's say I wanted to find all previous published versions of a single post.  The following works:

```
post = Post.first  # just grab something
published_posts = post.versions.find_all{ |v| v.published == true }
```

Etc.  Then I could do something with published_posts or whatever.  I'd love to make a named scope for this so I'm not putting the find_all block in my view but I can't figure out how to override the built-in functionality of the Version class.

I've tried various scopes in my Post class.  For example:

```
# I can't get this and other variations on this to work
scope :versions_published, 
  :where => 'self.versions.find_all{ |v| v.published == true }'
```

I also tried monkey patching the Version class but it doesn't like it very much.  I have a workaround, I was just hoping to learn more about the built-in Versioning Mongoid provides, especially how to extend the Version class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope you've defined is very, very wrong for two fundamental reasons:

1. You can't pass a string to the `:where` argument. You need to pass in a hash
2. scopes are defined on the class (`Post` in this case), so you cannot reference `self.versions` since `self` refers to the `Post` class and not to any specific post

The solution is to use the `matches` helper in Mongoid (which is a shortcut to [Mongo's $elemMatch](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-%24elemMatch)):

```
class Post
  #...
  scope :versions_published, where(:versions.matches => {:published => true})
  #...
end
```

I would not recommend monkeypatching the Version class unless you really know what you are doing.